# Suppress 'Warning: no access to tty' in ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, tty, tcsh

I have a short simple script, that compiles a `.c` file and runs it on a remote server running `tcsh` and then just gives back control to my machine (this is for school, I need my programs to work properly on the lab computers but want to edit them etc. on my machine). It runs commands this way:

```
ssh -T user@server << EOF
cd cs4400/$dest
gcc -o $efile $file
./$efile
EOF
```

So far it works fine, but it gives this warning every time I do this:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
```

I know this technically isn't a problem, but it's SUPER annoying. I'm trying to do school work, checking the output of my program etc., and this clutters everything, and I HATE it.

I'm running this version of ssh on my machine:

```
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

This version of tcsh on the server:

```
tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-unknown-linux)
```

And this version of ssh on the server:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be nothing that is specific to `tcsh` in your script, so just circumvent it. Example:

```
ssh -T user@server "/bin/bash -ec 'cd cs4400/$dest ; gcc -o $efile $file ; ./$efile'"
```

Comment: Sanity check: the `;`’s should be replaced by `&&`’s.

Comment: @Scott Thought about that, but decided to keep the original semantics at first. But you're right, so I added `-e` (`set -o errexit`), which is pretty much the same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The `-T` ssh option is disabling the forwarding of the local environment variables. Thus your TERM variable is either absent or undefined, in which case ssh cannot assign a proper pseudo terminal (pty), which usually means you cannot use command-line completion and command-line editing controls, etc. You can try to remedy the situation with: 
`TERM=vt100 ssh -T user@server ...`

Also check your envronment variables with: `set` and `set -o`.